# How to convert date and time separately in php and insert into MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the input value for date and time is entered by user in HTML.Both the input are set to **type="text**" because i am using **jQUERY** plugin to select date an time when clicked on the input field. Here is a quick snip of form with no css apply.

**form.html**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#day").datepicker();
$("#time").timepicker();

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<form>
<input type="text" name="day" id="day" autocomplete="off"required >
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" autocomplete="off"required >
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

Since the value passed from this form are directly string here is what i have tried till now on php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']));
  {
    $a = $_POST['day'];
    $b = $_POST['time'];
    $day = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($a));
    echo (gettype($day))//Here it returns string
  }
 ?>
```

Now this is the most common method i have found on internet and i just want to know whether it is a string type or it is actually a **date type** , secondly how to convert string to time ?

This is MYSQL table looks like

> id | day | time

The day column has data type set to **date**, the value from **name="day"** input field go into this

The time column has data type set to **time**, the value from **name="time"** input field go into this

I am aware of MYSQL function such as **STR_TO_DATE** but i am  using prepared statements to pass the value thus i can not directly pass function to it, my query looks like this:

> INSERT INTO table1 (' ', 'day' , 'time') VALUES (' ', :dayname , :timestamp);

Comment: sorry but i am not getting you what you exactly want to do ? how format you need to store in database ..

Comment: I recommend to store all your date and time as one unixtimestamp

$timestamp = strtotime($a. " " . $b);

It will be much more easy to manipulate.

Comment: @YagnikDetroja i need to store values from both input field that are date and time.But i need to store date input field as date data type where as time as time data type.While passing to php they are both string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know whether it is a string type or it is actually a
>   date type

When you send the data from your form to PHP, it comes in as a string.

```
$_POST['day'] = '08/01/2017';
$_POST['time'] = '12:30 AM';
```

> ... secondly how to convert string to time ...

Using [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php) causes the values to be NULL when binded in PDO, so you can do the following to format your time and date:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', $date);
$formatted_date = $dt->format('Y-m-d'); //YYYY-mm-dd

$formatted_time = date("G:i:s", strtotime("04:25 PM")); //HH:ii:ss
```

Here is an example using a PDO statement:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['day'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/yy', $date);
$formatted_date = $dt->format('Y-m-d'); //YYYY-mm-dd

$formatted_time = date("G:i:s", strtotime($time)); //HH-ii

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

$stmt = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (' ', 'day' , 'time') VALUES (' ', :dayname , :timestamp);");
$stmt->bindParam(':dayname', $formatted_date);
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $formatted_time);
$stmt->execute();
```